# Inserting Into a Generic Linked List

Tags: c#, generics, insert, linked-list

I'm having an issue inserting a new object into a linked list. I use a custom method called Insert that takes the object type and the index where it should be placed. However, when I insert the object, the list doesn't update. Any idea why?

The list:

```
        GenericLinkedList<string> bet = new GenericLinkedList<string>();
        bet.Add("a");
        bet.Add("b");
        bet.Add("c");
        bet.Add("d");

        //bet.Remove();
        bet.Insert("x", 2);
```

The Generic Linked List Class:

```
public class GenericLinkedList<T> where T : IComparable<T> 
{

    public GenericLinkedList()
    {
        count = 0;
        head = null;
    }

    #region Nested Node Class
    private class Node<T>
    {
        private T data;
        public T Data
        {
            get { return data; }
            set { data = value; }
        }

        private Node<T> next;
        public Node<T> Next
        {
            get { return next; }
            set { next = value; }
        }

        public Node<T> Previous { get; set; }


        public Node(T obj_t)
        {
            next = null;
            data = obj_t;
        }
        public Node()
        {
            next = null;
        }


    }
    #endregion

    private Node<T> head;
    private Node<T> tail;


    private int count;
    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            int num;
            if (count < 0)
                num = 0;
            else {
                num = count;
            }
            return num;
        }
    }
```

}

The Insert Method:

```
    public void Insert(T data, int index)
    {
        Node<T> replacedItem = new Node<T>();
        Node<T> newItem = new Node<T>(data);

        if (head == null)
        {
            head = new Node<T>(data);
            tail = head;
        }
        else
        {
            Node<T> current = head;
            Node<T> tempNode = new Node<T>();


            if (index > 0 && index <= count + 1)
            {
                int c = 0;
                while (current != null)
                {
                    if (c == index)
                    {
                        tempNode = current;
                        current = newItem;
                        current.Next = tempNode;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        current = current.Next;
                    }
                    c++;
                }
            }
            count++; 
        }
    }
```

The Add Method:

```
  public void Add(T data)
    {
        count++;

        if (head == null)
        {
            head = new Node<T>(data);
            tail = head;
        }
        else
        {
            tail.Next = new Node<T>(data);
            tail.Next.Previous = tail;
            tail = tail.Next;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you provide method `Add` too?

Comment: also in `Insert` method you increment `count` even if not add new node

Answer (score 0):

Need to add count++ in case head is null. Also count++ should go inside if(index>0&&index<=count+1)

```
public void Insert(T data, int index)
{
    Node<T> replacedItem = new Node<T>();
    Node<T> newItem = new Node<T>(data);

    if (head == null)
    {
        head = new Node<T>(data);
        tail = head;
        count++;
    }
    else
    {
        Node<T> current = head;
        Node<T> tempNode = new Node<T>();


        if (index > 0 && index <= count + 1)
        {
            int c = 0;
            while (current != null)
            {
                if (c == index)
                {
                    tempNode = current;
                    current = newItem;
                    current.Next = tempNode;
                }
                else
                {
                    current = current.Next;
                }
                c++;
            }
            count++;
        }             
    }
}
```

See if this helps.

Comment: if head is null, then count should be 0

Comment: We are adding first element in case head is null. Hence count should be increased else that element will not be counted.

Answer (score 0):

You not correctly add new item in your `Insert` method
in this place

```
tempNode = current; // save pointer to current item
current = newItem; // save in current new item
current.Next = tempNode; //set next to counter
```

but you don't change link from previous element, so when you again go from head you just miss your added item.

You need change this code something like

```
public void Insert(T data, int index)
{
    Node<T> replacedItem = new Node<T>();
    Node<T> newItem = new Node<T>(data);

    if (head == null)
    {
        head = new Node<T>(data);
        tail = head;
        count++;
    }
    else
    {
        Node<T> current = head;
        Node<T> tempNode = new Node<T>();


        if (index > 0 && index <= count + 1)
        {
            int c = 0;
            while (current != null)
            {
                if (c == index)
                {
                    tempNode = current;
                    current = newItem;

                    //update link from previous element
                    if(tempNode.Previous != null) 
                       tempNode.Previous.Next = current;

                    current.Next = tempNode;
                    current.Previous = tempNode.Previous;
                    tempNode.Previous = current;
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    current = current.Next;
                }
                c++;
            }
        }             
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2453973, I also think there is a problem, if you want to insert at 0 index